# why $(N-p-1)\hat\sigma^2$ have chi-squared distribution in estimate of coefficients linear least square model?

Tags: statistics

I was recently read The book Elements of Statistical Learning by Tibshirani et.al. 
this book explain that coefficients of linear model have normal distribution $\hat\beta\sim N(\beta,(X^TX)^{-1}\sigma^2)$ and estimate of $\sigma$ have $(N-p-1)\hat\sigma^2 \sim \sigma \mathcal X_{N-p-1}^2$ distribution that is chi-squared. but I don't understand why is it chi squared and why degree of freedom is $N-p-1$.(equation 3.11 on page 47)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277739/why-is-the-denominator-n-p-1-in-estimation-of-variance?rq=1.

Comment: I see it before. this post is about unbiased term of N-p-1 in denominator. I found it, but my question is about proof of chi-squared distribution of $\hat\sigma$

Comment: Assuming normality of errors of course, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20227/why-is-rss-distributed-chi-square-times-n-p?noredirect=1&lq=1.